# The getter 'displayName' was called on null. - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm working on this app where I signin user using google and fire store. If the user already exists and signs in. I get the error that the **displayName was called on null but when I hot reload the app the app works perfectly fine.**
Here is the code

````
```


final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");
final DateTime timestamp = DateTime.now();
MyUser currentUser;
bool isAuth = false;
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

void toggleDrawer() async {
  if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
  } else {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
  }
}

int currentIndex = 0;
List<Widget> listofPages = [
  Home(),
  MyOrders(),
  Saved(),
  Offers(),
  Refer(),
];
Widget currentScreen = Home();
String currentTitle = "gazzUp";
PageController pageController;
final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

var phoneNumber;

class CheckAuth extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckAuthState createState() => _CheckAuthState();
}

class _CheckAuthState extends State<CheckAuth> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: 1);
    googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen(
      (account) {
        handleGoogleSignIn(account);
      },
      onError: (err) {
        EasyLoading.showToast("Error Signing In: $err");
      },
    );
    googleSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((account) {
      handleGoogleSignIn(account);
    }).catchError((err) {
      print("Error Signing In: $err");
    });
  }

  handleGoogleSignIn(account) {
    if (account != null) {
      createGoogleUserInFirestore();
      setState(() {
        isAuth = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isAuth = false;
      });
    }
  }

  createGoogleUserInFirestore() async {
    // 1) Check if User Exists using UID
    final GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await userRef.doc(user.id).get();

    // 2) If User dowsn't exist, Take them to create account page

    if (!doc.exists) {
      final number = await Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GetPhoneNumber()));

      // final email = await Navigator.push(
      //     context,
      //     MaterialPageRoute(
      //       builder: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
      //     ));
      // 3) Get details from Create Account Page, Use them to make new user document in Users collection
      userRef.doc(user.id).set({
        "id": user.id,
        "e-mail": user.email,
        "photoUrl": user.photoUrl,
        "name": user.displayName,
        "timeStamp": timestamp,
        "phoneNumber": number,
      });
    }
    doc = await userRef.doc(user.id).get();
    currentUser = MyUser.fromDocument(doc);

    print(currentUser);
    print(currentUser.email);

    // 3) Get details from Create Account Page, Use them to make new user document in Users collection
  }

  googleLogIn() async {
    EasyLoading.show(status: "Signing You In");
    await googleSignIn.signIn();
    EasyLoading.dismiss();
    // if (isAuth = false) {
    //   EasyLoading.showToast("Couldn't Sign You In",
    //       toastPosition: EasyLoadingToastPosition.bottom);
    // } else {
    //   EasyLoading.showToast("Welcome",
    //       toastPosition: EasyLoadingToastPosition.bottom);
    // }
  }

  googleLogOut() async {
    EasyLoading.show(status: "Signing You Out");
    await googleSignIn.signOut();

    EasyLoading.dismiss();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isAuth ? mainView() : logInScreen();
  }

  Scaffold logInScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/bg.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 10.0, vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  RawMaterialButton(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Skip for Now",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              fontSize: 13.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                            color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                            size: 12,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Text(
                "gazzUp",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                    fontSize: 53,
                    fontFamily: "Cocogoose"),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 100.0,
              ),
              Container(
                child: KMainTextField(
                  label: "Enter Your Phone Number",
                  inputType: TextInputType.number,
                  obscureText: false,
                  leading: Icon(Icons.phone),
                  validator: (val) {
                    if (val.isEmpty) {
                      return "Can't be Empty";
                    } else if (val.length < 10 || val.length > 10) {
                      return "Enter a Valid Phone Number";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      phoneNumber = val;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              // SizedBox(
              //   height: 30.0,
              // ),
              RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Send OTP",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: "Cocogoose",
                          fontSize: 18.0),
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 120.0,
              ),
              GoogleAuthButton(
                borderColor: Colors.white,
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                elevation: 5.0,
                borderRadius: 50.0,
                onPressed: () {
                  try {
                    googleLogIn();
                  } catch (e) {
                    EasyLoading.showToast(e.toString());
                  }
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Scaffold mainView() {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      // appBar: AppBar(
      //   leading: currentIndex == 0
      //       ? Builder(
      //           builder: (BuildContext context) {
      //             return IconButton(
      //               icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
      //               onPressed: () {
      //                 _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
      //               },
      //             );
      //           },
      //         )
      //       : SizedBox(
      //           width: 0,
      //         ),
      //   elevation: 10.0,
      //   title: Transform(
      //     transform: currentIndex == 0
      //         ? Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
      //         : Matrix4.translationValues(-50.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      //     child: Text(
      //       currentTitle,
      //       style: TextStyle(
      //         color: Colors.white,
      //         fontFamily: currentIndex == 0 ? "Cocogoose" : "SegoeUi",
      //         fontSize: currentIndex == 0 ? 30.0 : 22.0,
      //         fontWeight: currentIndex == 0 ? null : FontWeight.bold,
      //       ),
      //     ),
      //   ),
      //   centerTitle: currentIndex == 0 ? true : false,
      //   actions: [
      //     currentIndex == 0
      //         ? Container(
      //             padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      //             child: Image(
      //               image: AssetImage("assets/images/qrCode.png"),
      //               fit: BoxFit.cover,
      //             ),
      //           )
      //         : Padding(
      //             padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
      //             child: Icon(
      //               Icons.notifications_none_outlined,
      //               size: 25,
      //             ),
      //           ),
      //   ],
      // ),
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black26, offset: Offset(0, 4), blurRadius: 6)
              ],
              gradient: RadialGradient(
                center: Alignment.topLeft,
                radius: 4.0,
                colors: [
                  Colors.deepOrange,
                  Colors.red,
                  Colors.pink,
                ],
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    toggleDrawer();
                  },
                  child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.menu,
                        size: 30,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "gazzUp",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontFamily: "Cocogoose"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                // IconButton(
                //   icon: Icon(
                //     Icons.qr_code,
                //     color: Colors.white,
                //   ),
                //   onPressed: () {},
                // )
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => QRPage()));
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/images/qrCode.png"),
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        preferredSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 60.0),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: RadialGradient(
                  center: Alignment.topLeft,
                  colors: [
                    // Colors.orange,
                    Colors.deepOrange,
                    Colors.red,
                    Colors.pink,
                  ],
                  radius: 2,
                ),
              ),
              accountName: Text(
                currentUser.displayName == null
                    ? "User"
                    : currentUser.displayName,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    letterSpacing: 1.0,
                    fontFamily: "SegoeUi"),
              ),
              accountEmail: Row(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.location_on,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 10.0,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 3.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Delhi",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                    height: 10,
                    width: 0.5,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    // currentUser.email != null ? currentUser.email : "No Email",
                    currentUser.email,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange[200],
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(currentUser.photoUrl),
              ),
            ),
            KListTile(
              leading: Icons.list,
              title: "List Your Pump",
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    CupertinoPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ListingPage(),
                    ));
                toggleDrawer();
              },
            ),
            KDivider(),
            KListTile(
              leading: Icons.thumb_up,
              title: "Feedback",
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    CupertinoPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => FeedbackPage(),
                    ));
                toggleDrawer();
              },
            ),
            KListTile(
              leading: Icons.contacts,
              title: "Contact Us",
            ),
            KListTile(
              leading: Icons.help,
              title: "Terms and Policies",
            ),
            KDivider(),
            KListTile(
              leading: Icons.settings,
              title: "Settings",
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    CupertinoPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => SettingsPage(),
                    ));
                toggleDrawer();
              },
            ),
            KListTile(
              leading: Icons.exit_to_app,
              title: "Log Out",
              onTap: () {
                googleLogOut();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: currentScreen,
        bucket: bucket,
      ),

      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.deepOrange : Colors.white,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
          child: Icon(Icons.home,
              size: 35, color: currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              currentIndex = 0;
              currentScreen = Home();
              currentTitle = "gazzUp";
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 70,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black26, blurRadius: 5)],
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            KBottomBarIcon(
                currentIndex == 1
                    ? FontAwesomeIcons.solidFileAlt
                    : FontAwesomeIcons.fileAlt, () {
              setState(() {
                currentIndex = 1;
                currentScreen = MyOrders();
                currentTitle = "My Orders";
              });
            }, "My Orders",
                currentIndex == 1 ? Colors.deepOrange : Colors.black),
            KBottomBarIcon(
                currentIndex == 2
                    ? FontAwesomeIcons.solidHeart
                    : FontAwesomeIcons.heart, () {
              setState(() {
                currentIndex = 2;
                currentScreen = Saved();
                currentTitle = "Saved";
              });
            }, "Saved", currentIndex == 2 ? Colors.deepOrange : Colors.black),
            Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                child: RawMaterialButton(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.home,
                    size: 40,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                )),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              child: RawMaterialButton(
                splashColor: Colors.white,
                highlightColor: Colors.white,
                constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    currentIndex = 3;
                    currentScreen = Offers();
                    currentTitle = "Offers";
                  });
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Image(
                      image: currentIndex != 3
                          ? AssetImage(
                              "assets/images/offer.png",
                            )
                          : AssetImage("assets/images/solidOffer.png"),
                      height: 26,
                      width: 26,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Offers",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9.5, letterSpacing: -.75),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            KBottomBarIcon(
                currentIndex == 4
                    ? FontAwesomeIcons.solidHandshake
                    : FontAwesomeIcons.handshake, () {
              setState(() {
                currentIndex = 4;
                currentScreen = Refer();
                currentTitle = "Refer and Earn";
              });
            }, "Refer & Earn",
                currentIndex == 4 ? Colors.deepOrange : Colors.black),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      // bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
      //   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      //   currentIndex: pageIndex,
      //   onTap: onTap,
      //   items: [
      //     BottomNavigationBarItem(
      //       label: "My Orders",
      //       icon: Icon(
      //         FontAwesomeIcons.fileAlt,
      //       ),
      //       activeIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidFileAlt),
      //     ),
      //     BottomNavigationBarItem(
      //       label: "Saved",
      //       icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.heart),
      //       activeIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidHeart),
      //     ),
      //     BottomNavigationBarItem(
      //       icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.trophy, color: Colors.white),
      //     ),
      //     BottomNavigationBarItem(
      //       icon: Icon(
      //         FontAwesomeIcons.trophy,
      //       ),
      //     ),
      //     BottomNavigationBarItem(
      //         icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.handshake),
      //         activeIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidHandshake)),
      //   ],
      //   activeColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      // ),
    );
  }
}

```
````

Debug Console Shows This
==============

```
Launching lib\main.dart on POCOPHONE F1 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:60201/1xgZZsjBYws=/ws

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building CheckAuth(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _CheckAuthState#4d2e1):
The getter 'displayName' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: displayName

The relevant error-causing widget was
CheckAuth
lib\MainPages\SplashScreen.dart:55
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _CheckAuthState.mainView
package:trial_1/Services/CheckAuth.dart:440
#2      _CheckAuthState.build
package:trial_1/Services/CheckAuth.dart:156
#3      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4744
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4627
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
W/DynamiteModule(20226): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(20226): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(20226): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/example.trial_(20226): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The getter 'displayName' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: displayName
The relevant error-causing widget was
CheckAuth
lib\MainPages\SplashScreen.dart:55
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/example.trial_(20226): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/TetheringManager(20226): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.trial_1
V/NativeCrypto(20226): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 287 native methods...
W/example.trial_(20226): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller(20226): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/example.trial_(20226): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/example.trial_(20226): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/example.trial_(20226): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/example.trial_(20226): Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (greylist, JNI, allowed)
W/example.trial_(20226): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/example.trial_(20226): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/example.trial_(20226): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/flutter (20226): Instance of 'MyUser'
I/flutter (20226): manavarora191100@gmail.com
I/flutter (20226): Instance of 'MyUser'
I/flutter (20226): manavarora191100@gmail.com
```

**As you can see the instance of user is displaying after and the displayName is getting called earlier so I guess this is the issue but I'm not sure as to how to solve it.**

Comment: NOTE: The User has a Display Name is the firestore Database

Comment: the display name is called before getting the value in it

Comment: try to initialize it with empty string till the data fetches

Comment: The error is no more but it is not updating itself once the data has been fetched. Like the user was being fetched after the value was called so I provided a ternary operation that checks if the user is not equal to null and if it is it should show a progress indicator. The problem is that the indicator is not going away even after the data has been fetched

Comment: UPDATE: @JanviPatel The data is updated but only if I rebuild the page i.e. I need to go to another page and then come back for the info to show up

Comment: yes that means it dosnt have a state keep it in a setState() it will work fine

Comment: let me know if worked  ??

Comment: @JanviPatel it worked like a charm. Just called set state after the data was fetched and it works perfectly. Thank You

Comment: welcome if i post an aswer can you upvote my answer please ?

Comment: Have a look at https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state

Comment: @JanviPatel Yeah Sure why not

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Already found the solution. Regardless thanks for reaching out to help. I have posted more questions so could you take a look in them too. Please

Comment: @JanviPatel Can you also Please.

Comment: @JanviPatel or OP: if you managed to solve this problem, can you post an answer? That signals to others, and the system, that helps has been given here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialize it with an empty string till the data fetches and  keep it in a setState() it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

### **The Final Solution:**

Added a ternary Operation to check if the user is not null.

```
accountName: currentUser != null
              ? Text(
                  currentUser.displayName,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      letterSpacing: 1.0,
                      fontFamily: "SegoeUi"),
                )
              : Container(
                  height: 2.0,
                  width: 40.0,
                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
```

Then called setState where I print the Username(i.e where it finally has a value) so that it updates on the UI.

```
doc = await userRef.doc(user.id).get();
    currentUser = MyUser.fromDocument(doc);

    print(currentUser);
    print(currentUser.email);
    setState(() {});
```